# Crystal Report allowing user to change width of columns at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, .net-4.0

I am using creating reports in Crystal Reports. Came across requirement to let user change the width of columns while user using application.

I have searched a lot but no luck. Please guide in right direction is it possible if yes how?

Comment: Can you elaborate more, how the user has these settings? Via some sort of User Interface before report generation or different settings for the different user (pre-defined?)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible via RAS but it would be too much of a pain. So I would advise you to rethink. Can you instead identify 2-3 typical layouts the user wishes to switch between? Then, give the user a parameter to control that aspect. The parameter can then control conditional suppress of sections (Detail a, Detail b, Detail c), each with a different layout.